# My NN has less than 1% accuracy rate, what's wrong with my model/dataset?

Tags: neural-network, dataset

**Data info**

```
X_train.shape
```

(20160, 44)

```
y_train.shape
```

(20160,)

```
#first row of the dataset
X_train.values[0]
```

array([93., 87., 85., 79., 78., 74., 64., 60., 60., 56., 51., 41., 37.,
       36.,  0., 36.,  0., 31.,  0.,  0., 32.,  0.,  0., 31.,  0., 23.,
       22., 17.,  0.,  0., 14.,  0., 12.,  8.,  5.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])

```
y_train.values[0]
```

106.0

**Neural Network**

```
n_cols = len(X_train.columns)
es = EarlyStopping(patience = 5)
adam = Adam(lr = 0.0001)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(n_cols, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (n_cols,)))
model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer = adam, loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = X_train.shape[0], epochs = 100, validation_data = (X_test, y_test), callbacks = [es], verbose = 0)
```

The code above gives me a maximum accuracy of around 0.0025, I've also tried normalising X_train but same results.

A linear regression with the exact same data returns an R2 of 0.97

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You note that `y_train.values[0]` returns `106.0` - is that correct? Sigmoid activation binds the output to between 0 and 1, so it's not possible for it to predict a 106.

Try changing the activation for your final layer to relu too.

You should also switch to a more regression-appropriate metric like mean_squared_error or R2. Accuracy is more of a classification thing.

Comment: Good point, I've missed that... I just re-run the code with 1000 epochs and got 10% accuracy (the acc curve flattens around epoch 600).

Comment: Is this a regression problem? If so I'd also change the metric. Accuracy really makes sense in a classification context. You could use mean_squared_error like your loss, or manually calculate the R^2 metric for y_train and yhat

Comment: Yes, it's a regression problem. I've changed the metrics and I'm getting the same results as with linear regression. `NN MSE: 25.557850335785563
NN R2: 0.97239258036107` Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :). If you're happy the question's answered, please think about accepting the answer.